# Understanding StopIteration handling inside generators for non-trivial case

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, generator, stopiteration

I am helping maintain some code that now includes automated Python 3.7 testing. This led me to some issues related to [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) "Change StopIteration handling inside generators". My naive understanding was that you could use a try-except block to modify old code to be compatible with all python versions, e.g.

Old code:

```
def f1():
    it = iter([0])
    while True:
        yield next(it)

print(list(f1()))
# [0] (in Py 3.6)
# "RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration" (in Py 3.7;
# or using from __future__ import generator_stop)
```

Becomes:

```
def f2():
    it = iter([0])
    while True:
        try:
            yield next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            return 

print(list(f2()))
# [0] (in all Python versions)
```

For this trivial example, it works, but I have found for some more complex code I am re-factoring it does not. Here is a minimal example with Py 3.6:

```
class A(list):
    it = iter([0])
    def __init__(self):
        while True:
            self.append(next(self.it))

class B(list):
    it = iter([0])
    def __init__(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.append(next(self.it))
            except StopIteration:
                raise

class C(list):
    it = iter([0])
    def __init__(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.append(next(self.it))
            except StopIteration:
                return  # or 'break'

def wrapper(MyClass):
    lst = MyClass()
    for item in lst:
        yield item

print(list(wrapper(A)))
# [] (wrong output)
print(list(wrapper(B)))
# [] (wrong output)
print(list(wrapper(C)))
# [0] (desired output)
```

I know that the `A` and `B` examples are exactly equivalent and that the `C` case is the correct way compatible with Python 3.7 (I also know that re-factoring to a `for` loop would make sense for many examples, including this contrived one).

But the question is why do the examples with `A` and `B` produce an empty list `[]`, rather than `[0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two cases have an uncaught `StopIteration` raised in the class's `__init__`. The `list` constructor handles this just fine in Python 3.6 (with possibly a warning, depending on the version). However, the exception propagates *before* `wrapper` gets a chance to iterate: the line that effectively fails is `lst = MyClass()`, and the loop `for item in lst:` never runs, causing the generator to be empty.

When I run this code in Python 3.6.4, I get the following warning on both `print` lines (for `A` and `B`):

```
DeprecationWarning: generator 'wrapper' raised StopIteration
```

The conclusion here is twofold:

1. Don't let the iterator run out on its own. It's your job to check when it stops. This is easy to do with a `for` loop, but has to be done manually with a `while` loop. Case `A` is a good illustration.
2. Don't re-raise the internal exception. Return `None` instead. Case `B` is just not the way to go. A `break` or `return` would work correctly in the `except` block, as you did in `C`.

Given that `for` loops are syntactic sugar for the try-except block in `C`, I would generally recommend their use, even with manual invocations of `iter`:

```
class D(list):
    it = iter([0])
    def __init__(self):
        for item in it:
            self.append(item)
```

This version is functionally equivalent to `C`, and does all the bookkeeping for you. There are very few cases that require an actual `while` loop (skipping calls to `next` being one that comes to mind, but even those cases can be rewritten with a nested loop).

Comment: Interesting I get no warning with Python 3.6.6; but I think your explanation is basically correct, thanks! I guess this is why they introduced the PEP to illuminate such bugs!

Comment: @Chris_Rands. This is exactly why even with a manual call to `iter` I still prefer a `for` loop. It's basically syntactic sugar for exactly the try-catch block in option `C`. Saves a lot of typing, and it's *very* seldom that you need anything else, given the nature of the process.

Comment: In this case my real example is not as contrived as the one I showed but in general I agree

Comment: "The list wrapper handles this just fine in Python 3.6"-- to be clear, it's not the list wrapper handling it right? It's only because the `yield` turns the whole thing into a generator function (but yes you're correct that the generator terminates at the `lst = MyClass()` line), yes?

Comment: (Without the `yield` there would still be a `StopIteration` raised)

Comment: "A pass or break would work correctly in the except block" Woudln't `pass` result in an infinite loop?

Comment: @tobias_k. Sure would. I meant break or return. Fixed now.

Comment: @Chris_Rands. Correct. The issue is that *generators* should mark a normal return with a return, while `StopIteration` should be used only internally by the Python machinery. Python 3.6 does not fully enforce this but an exception is still an exception, so the wrapper never gets to yield anything.

Comment: @Chris_Rands. By "list wrapper" I actually meant `list` constructor, which accepts the `StopIteration` as a normal part of business.